# Why does my C++ code simply stop running after a specific point in the program?

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a C++ code in my hand that doesn't go on with the execution of the program after a certain point. I don't understand why this is happening. Here's the code itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int m;
    cin>>m;

    map<int,int>cnt;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        cnt[x]=min(cnt[x]+1,2);
        cout<<x<<endl;//for debugging purposes. These do get executed and printed.
    }
    cout<<"this won't get executed";//isn't printed

    (cnt.end()--)->second=1;

    for(auto & it : cnt)
    {
        cout<<(it.first)<<" ";
        it.second--;
    }

    for(auto it=cnt.end()--;it!=--cnt.begin();it--)
        if(it->second)cout<<(it->first)<<" ";
}
```

The code is for an algorithm problem, so I don't think the details will be useful. The 'cout' command after the first for loop isn't being executed. Neither is anything beyond that point. I don't know why this is happening. If someone could enlighten me, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try printing the values of m and x.  Does an exception occur?

Comment: If I hardcode in some values for `m` and `x` instead of using user input, I [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/9d5bs6z83) this behavior. What inputs are you actually providing?

Comment: `it!=--cnt.begin()` is this okay?

Comment: Probably `cout` just isn't flushed before you try to access something you shoudn"t: `(cnt.end()--)->second=1;` accesses a copy of the end() iterator using the arrow iterator, not the value after the decrement.

Comment: @drescherjm Sounds like we have a philosophical question, not programming. What is before the beginning?

Comment: @NathanPierson Here's two different ones:

5
1 2 3 4 5
-------
6
1 1 2 2 3 3
-------
I'm getting this error for both these inputs.

Comment: `it!=--cnt.begin()` this is nonsense, and I cannot fathom why you're not using [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/rbegin) regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've just implemented them. I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: If your toolchain supports it, turn on [ASAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

Comment: What happens if you replace each `cout` with `cerr`? Have you tried running your program in a debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the problem [if you used reverse iterators correctly](https://godbolt.org/z/16Thr4nov) and remember to flush stdout if you're expecting inline feedback.

Comment: Cout is being executed, but is not flushed, and the next line results in a spectacular crash, due to the shown bug. The End.

Comment: Looks like there is undefined behavior here: `cnt[x]=min(cnt[x]+1,2);`.    At the start of the program, the `map` is empty.  So, what is the value of `cnt[x]` when the map is empty?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews • `cnt[x]` will insert a new key-value pair into the map upon access.